# No such file or directory error even the file exists in Java

Tags: java, lda

I am a newbie to Java and I wish to run the library `JGibbLDA`. I did as required by the document, enter the root directory of `JGibbLDA-v.1.0` and input the command:

```
java -mx512M -cp bin:lib/args4j-2.0.6.jar jgibblda.LDA -est -alpha 0.5 -beta 0.1 -ntopics 100 -niters 1000 -savestep 100 -twords 20 -dfile models/data/data.txt
```

But an error occurs:

```
Read Dataset Error: /models/data/data.txt (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /models/data/data.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at jgibblda.LDADataset.readDataSet(LDADataset.java:154)
at jgibblda.Model.initNewModel(Model.java:476)
at jgibblda.Estimator.init(Estimator.java:45)
at jgibblda.LDA.main(LDA.java:49)
Fail to read training data!
```

I don't know why there is a `/` before the directory in the error log message. But the `models/data/data.txt` really exist and I can enter `models/data` at the root directory properly. The related code of the library is as below:

```
public static LDADataset readDataSet(BufferedReader reader, Dictionary dict){
    try {
        //read number of document
        String line;
        line = reader.readLine();
        int M = Integer.parseInt(line);
        System.out.println("NewM:" + M);

        LDADataset data = new LDADataset(M, dict);
        for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i){
            line = reader.readLine();

            data.setDoc(line, i);
        }

        return data;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Read Dataset Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have also tried `../../models/data/data.txt` but also failed. Do you know how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is looking for an absolute path and you are passing a relative path.

The error says:

```
/models/data/data.txt (No such file or directory)
^
|--- This is the root of your filesystem
```

Then you must pass the full path, try with full path (for example /home/youruser/project/models/data/data.txt):

```
java -mx512M -cp bin:lib/args4j-2.0.6.jar jgibblda.LDA -est -alpha 0.5 -beta 0.1 -ntopics 100 -niters 1000 -savestep 100 -twords 20 -dfile FULL_PATH
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the error still exists: `Read Dataset Error: /./models/data/data.txt (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Then pass the full path

Comment: But it works when I transfer it to full directory. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In method `Model.initNewModel(LDACmdOption option)` the filename for the dataset is constructed as

```
dir + File.separator + dfile
```

If `dir` is empty the filename will start from the root directory. To avoid this behavior you can use the option `-dir` to specify the data directory.

Running it as

```
java -mx512M -cp bin:lib/args4j-2.0.6.jar jgibblda.LDA -est -alpha 0.5 \
   -beta 0.1 -ntopics 100 -niters 1000 -savestep 100 -twords 20 \
   -dir /home/youruser/project/models/data/ \
   -dfile data.txt
```

would read the file `data.txt` from directory `/home/youruser/project/models/data/`. All generated files would also be stored in `/home/youruser/project/models/data/`.